# Required fields in flex

Tags: apache-flex, validation, required-field

I've got a question about flex.
I have a form and the email is required.
I googled this and found  the following solution:

```
<mx:FormItem label="Email" id="emailFormItem"  width="100%" styleName="formEven" required="true">                   
<mx:TextInput id="emailTextInput" width="100%" text="{user.email}"/></mx:FormItem>
```

The problem is that when I press ok the call is still made.
I know you have to validate the following by yourself but does anyone has an idea how I can validate the field(s)?

Solution:

I've found a solution for this:

You can create a validator for each field you want to validate and then create this function:

```
private function isValid():Boolean {
            var failedValidators:Array = Validator.validateAll([emailValidator, userNameValidator, languageValidator, firstNameValidator, lastNameValidator]);
            return failedValidators.length == 0;
        }
```

This can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I generally do is create a method called something like isSubmitEnabled or isFormComplete.  I call it on keyUp on every field that is required and check for values in all of the fields (and any other validation I want to do) and then as long as everything checks out I set the submit button to be enabled otherwise I set the submit button to be disabled.  As long as you disable the button when you start then you should be good to go.

I have used this method several times and find it to be the easiest to use and especially to maintain.  I will look at the docs and see if I can see what you can do with the required attribute on the form item though.

**Update:**

According to the docs:

> This property controls the indicator
>   display only. You must attach a
>   validator to the children if you
>   require input validation.

What you want is mx.validators.Validator (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/validators/Validator.html)

```
 <mx:Validator id="reqValid" required="true"
    source="{fname}" property="text" 
    valid="handleValid(event)" invalid="handleValid(event)"/>
```

See the code examples on that link to see how to use it.  The example is actually exactly what you are looking for I think.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="a1" itemClick="usdradio(event);"/>
        <fx:Model id="creditcard">
            <card>  
                <cardType>{cardTypeCombo.selectedItem.data}</cardType>
                <cardNumber>{cardNumberInput.text}</cardNumber>
            </card>
        </fx:Model>
        <mx:CreditCardValidator id="ccV" 

                                cardTypeSource="{creditcard}" cardTypeProperty="cardType"
                                cardNumberSource="{creditcard}" cardNumberProperty="cardNumber"
                                trigger="{myButton}" triggerEvent="click"
                                cardTypeListener="{cardTypeCombo}"
                                cardNumberListener="{cardNumberInput}"
                                valid="Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!')"/>

        <mx:ArrayCollection id="dp">
            <fx:Object label="American Express" data="American Express"/>
            <fx:Object label="Diners Club" data="Diners Club"/>
            <fx:Object label="Discover" data="Discover"/>
            <fx:Object label="MasterCard" data="MasterCard"/>
            <fx:Object label="Visa" data="Visa"/>
        </mx:ArrayCollection>

        <mx:CurrencyValidator source="{priceUS}" property="text" precision="2" 


                              trigger="{myButton2}" triggerEvent="click" 
                              valid="Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!')"/>
```